# Выбор столбца через iloc/loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть датафрейм с метриками: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
low - это 25-й квантиль, up - 75-й квантиль. Я создал список с метриками из датасета и хочу написать функцию, которая бы проходилась по каждой метрике из датасета и присваивала ей значения квантилей. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но с текущим кодом получаю ошибку: too many indexers.
Пример кода:

```
metric_list = feed[['users', 'views', 'likes', 'ctr']]
for metric in metric_list:
    q_25 = now_df.iloc[:, now_df.columns.str.contains('low.*'), metric].iloc[0]
    q_75 = now_df.iloc[:, now_df.columns.str.contains('up.*'), metric].iloc[0]
    iqr = q_75 - q_25
    if now_df.loc[:, (metric, metric)].iloc[0] < q_25 - a * iqr or info_current.loc[:, (metric, metric)].iloc[0] > q_75 + a * iqr:
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Ну потому что вы колонки два раза выбираете, а можно только один. Какие колонки вы хотите выбрать на каждом шаге цикла, распишите. У меня есть предположение, но лучше когда вся инфа прямо в вопросе

Comment: @CrazyElf в переменной q_25 я хочу пройтись по колонкам users, views, likes, ctr и все, которые содержат 'low' в названии. В переменной q_75 пройтись по тем же колонкам, но уже с 'up' в названии. Я добавил в вопрос небольшое дополнение к коду.

Comment: @MaxU как раз выбрать столбцы, названия которых начинаются с low и up у меня получилось, не получается другое)

Comment: @Sokolymba, если вы думаете, что мы сейчас бросимся угадывать что значит "другое" и что же вы хотите получить, то вы ошибаетесь )

Comment: @MaxU в переменной q_25 должно храниться значение метрик из списка metric_list и также 25-е квантили из столбцов "low_". В переменной q_75 должно храниться значение метрик из списка metric_list и 75-е квантили из столбцов "low_". Суть в том, что я пытаюсь построить систему отслеживания аномалий, поэтому должна проверяться каждая метрика из списка на соответствие интервалу)

Comment: @Sokolymba, вам что-то мешает привести в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать все столбцы, наименования которых начинаются с `"low_"` и с `"up_"`:

```
q_25 = now_df.filter(regex=r"^low_")
q_75 = now_df.filter(regex=r"^up_")
```